# sipsimpleclient SDK session.connect() "TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)"

Tags: python, session, sip

I'm using SIPSimpleClient SDK to build a simple script that can create a SIP session with some  other SIP user. I started by copying and pasting the Hello World example [here](http://sipsimpleclient.org/projects/sipsimpleclient/wiki/SipDeveloperGuide) to a python script and executing it. I get the following error

```
Placing call to sip:3333@sip2sip.info, press Enter to quit the program
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 824, in runUntilCurrent
    call.func(*call.args, **call.kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlib/coros.py", line 197, in _do_send
    waiter.switch(result)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlib/api.py", line 235, in _spawn_startup
    return cb(*args, **kw)
  File "helloworldoriginal.py", line 38, in _NH_SIPApplicationDidStart
    self.session.connect(self.callee, routes, [AudioStream(account)])
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

After giving up on that script, I built my own script from scratch based on the Hello World example and using the documentation provided [here](http://download.ag-projects.com/SipClient/SIPSIMPLE-Manual.pdf). First, a TestClass object is created (a child class of the SIPApplication class). The **init** method in the TestClass calls self.start(FileStorage('config')) at which point a SIPApplicationDidStart messgae triggers my _NH_SIPApplicationDidStart method. All good so far, and the lines in this method all work as expected. When the DNSLookup of the callee is successful, it sends a DNSLookupDidSucceed message, which triggers the _NH_DNSLookupDidSucceed method. Whithin this method, I create a new Session object(self.session = Session(account)) which seems to work fine (I can print attributes of this object at this time). The problem seems to be in the self.session.connect(self.callee, self.routes, [AudioStream(account)]) line. This is where I get the same error as in the Hello World example. You can see this connect method and its parameters on page 61 of the documentation.

```
************ START ************
SIP Application Did Start
SIP URI parse of callee OK
DNS Lookup Did Succeed
Will Call sip:kulzer@sip2sip.info
Session Initiated
Session State: None
Session account: Account('xxxxxx')
Session Direction: None
Session Start Time: None
error: Exception occured in observer <__main__.TestClass object at 0x35329d0> while handling notification 'DNSLookupDidSucceed'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/application/notification.py", line 216, in post_notification
    observer.handle_notification(notification)
  File "<string>", line 1, in handle_notification
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sipsimple/threading/__init__.py", line 100, in wrapper
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sipsimple/application.py", line 277, in handle_notification
    handler(notification)
  File "testcall.py", line 84, in _NH_DNSLookupDidSucceed
    self.session.connect(self.callee, self.routes, [AudioStream(account)])
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
DNS Lookup Did Succeed
Will Call sip:kulzer@sip2sip.info
Session Initiated
Session State: None
Session account: Account('xxxxxx')
Session Direction: None
Session Start Time: None
error: Exception occured in observer <__main__.TestClass object at 0x35329d0> while handling notification 'DNSLookupDidSucceed'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/application/notification.py", line 216, in post_notification
    observer.handle_notification(notification)
  File "<string>", line 1, in handle_notification
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sipsimple/threading/__init__.py", line 100, in wrapper
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sipsimple/application.py", line 277, in handle_notification
    handler(notification)
  File "testcall.py", line 84, in _NH_DNSLookupDidSucceed
    self.session.connect(self.callee, self.routes, [AudioStream(account)])
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
Press "Enter" to exit.
```

I just put Xs where the program output my account name. I just don't understand what is going on here. Does anybody know why they would post an example program that throws errors? Or is this just a problem on my end? Bonus points if you can tell me what the @run_in_green_thread line is used for or why it sends the DNSLookupDidSucceed message twice.
BTW, I'm using Ubuntu Trusty Tahr Server through SSH. I'm doing this for a company so they set up the environment. I assume all of the dependencies are installed correctly, since I can use the sipclients from the command line (such as sip-message and sip-audio-session). I've also looked through the code of those sipclients (not all of them) and they seem to use the same session.connect() method without this problem. There seems to be little help for this SDK outside of the official documentation.
Thanks in advance, and here is the code for my script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import time
from sipsimple.application import SIPApplication
from sipsimple.storage import FileStorage
from sipsimple.session import Session
from application.notification import NotificationCenter
from sipsimple.account import AccountManager
from sipsimple.lookup import DNSLookup, DNSLookupError
from sipsimple.core import SIPURI, ToHeader, SIPCoreError
from sipsimple.streams import AudioStream
from sipsimple.threading.green import run_in_green_thread

callee = "sip:kulzer@sip2sip.info"
#callee = "sip:3333@sip2sip.info"

class TestClass(SIPApplication):
    def __init__(self):
        SIPApplication.__init__(self)
        self.session = None
        self.callee = callee
        self.routes = None
        self.start(FileStorage('config'))

        #make sure our methods are called when a notification is sent
        notification_center = NotificationCenter()
        notification_center.add_observer(self)

    #not sure what this does. I get the same error whether it's here or not
    @run_in_green_thread 

    #After the self.start(FileStorage('storage')) line is executed in __init__,
    #a SIPApplicationDidStart message is sent, which invokes this method.
    def _NH_SIPApplicationDidStart(self, notification):
        print 'SIP Application Did Start'

        try:#this line somehow puts the address into a usable format
            self.callee = ToHeader(SIPURI.parse(self.callee))
            print 'SIP URI parse of callee OK'
        except Exception as e:
            print 'ERROR1: %s' % e
            self.stop()

        try:#This line looks up the callee in the proxy
            self.routes = DNSLookup().lookup_sip_proxy(self.callee.uri, ['udp']).wait()
        except Exception as e:
            print 'ERROR2: %s' %e


    #Once a session is successfuly created, a SIPSessionDidStart message is
    #sent which invokes this method
    def _NH_SIPSessionDidStart(self, notification):
        print 'SIP Session Did Start'

    def _NH_SIPSessionDidFail(self, notification):
        print 'SIP Session Did Fail'

    def _NH_SIPSessionGotRingIndication(self, notification):
        print 'SIP Session Got Ring Indication'

    def _NH_SIPSessionWillStart(self, notification):
        print 'SIP Session Will Start'

    def _NH_DNSLookupDidSucceed(self, notification):
        print 'DNS Lookup Did Succeed\nWill Call %s' %self.callee.uri
        account = AccountManager().default_account

        #These lines begin the creation of a session within the SIPApplication
        self.session = Session(account)
        print 'Session Initiated'
        print 'Session State: %s' %self.session.state
        print 'Session account: %s' %self.session.account
        print 'Session Direction: %s' %self.session.direction
        print 'Session Start Time: %s' %self.session.start_time

        #THIS SEEMS TO BE THE PROBLEM LINE
        self.session.connect(self.callee, self.routes, [AudioStream(account)])

def main():
    print '\n************ START ************'
    application = TestClass()
    time.sleep(3)
    print ('Press "Enter" to exit.')
    raw_input()
    application.stop()
    print '************* END *************\n'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in this line

```
self.session.connect(self.callee, self.routes, [AudioStream(account)])
```

AudioStream() takes no arguments, so it should be modified to the following

```
self.session.connect(self.callee, self.routes, [AudioStream()])
```